# How optimizing code on fast_bitrix in python?

Tags: python

I am using fast_bitrix in Python
Need optimizing code speed
The problem is that it processes the first request quickly
Then since it is not asynchronous it slows down very much
I would like to combine it, but I don’t know how, any ideas?

```
def get_leads_without_deal():

  lead_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

  #print('начал отработку')

  # В работе
  leads_raw_1 = b.get_all(
    'crm.lead.list',
    params={
      'select': ['ID','ASSIGNED_BY_ID'],
      'filter': {'STATUS_ID': ['IN_PROCESS','UC_YC6E5E','UC_QVBLZH'],
                 'ASSIGNED_BY_ID': ['11','245','279','565','847', 
                                    '267','289', 
                                    '231','277','355','357','687','845','269','233','255']
                }
    })
  #bar = IncrementalBar('Лиды_без_дел', max=len(leads_raw_1))
  for lead_raw in leads_raw_1:
    #print(lead_raw['ID'])
    leads = b.get_all(
      'crm.activity.list', 
      params={
        'select': ['OWNER_ID'],
        'filter': {'OWNER_ID': lead_raw['ID'],
                  'COMPLETED': 'N'}
      })
    #print(leads)
    #bar.next()
    if len(leads)!= 0:
      pass
    else:
      if lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '247':
        pass
      elif lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '11':
        lead_count[0] += 1
      elif lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '245':
        lead_count[1] += 1
      elif lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '279':
        lead_count[2] += 1
      elif lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '565':
        lead_count[3] += 1
      elif lead_raw['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] == '847':
        lead_count[4] += 1
      else:
        lead_count[5] += 1
```

I tried call() and get_by_ID(), so this not my answer or i not understand how to use this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `numba` to optimize your code it should work in better way if you added decorator `@jit`,
use those two line,

```
from numba import jit

@jit()
get_leads_without_deal():...
```

if not working in your case try to learn and use cython it must work much better.